# Parsing html, jsoup

Tags: android

I am trying to extract the specific content in html using **Jsoup**. Below is the sample html content.

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <a class="CategoryTitle ArticleAllDC" title="рубрика" href="http://tlt.ru/articles.php?category=3">Культура</a>
                <span class="ArticleMainDCnew ArticleAllDC" title="источник">&nbsp;/&nbsp;TLT.ru</span>
                <span class="ArticleMainDCnew ArticleAllDC" title="дата время [просмотры] (комментарии)">&nbsp;/&nbsp;02.04 12:35 [85] (0)</span>
            </span>
        </p>
```

I want to get **`02.04 12:35 [85] (0)`**. Help me please, how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method without any optimisations:

```
String input = "<span style=\"white-space:nowrap;\">" +
            "                <a class=\"CategoryTitle ArticleAllDC\" title=\"рубрика\" href=\"http://tlt.ru/articles.php?category=3\">Культура</a>" +
            "                <span class=\"ArticleMainDCnew ArticleAllDC\" title=\"источник\">&nbsp;/&nbsp;TLT.ru</span>" +
            "                <span class=\"ArticleMainDCnew ArticleAllDC\" title=\"дата время [просмотры] (комментарии)\">&nbsp;/&nbsp;02.04 12:35 [85] (0)</span>" +
            "            </span>" +
            "        </p>";
Document d = Jsoup.parse(input);
Elements elements = d.select("span[title^=дата]");
System.out.println(elements.get(0).html().replaceAll("&nbsp;/&nbsp;",""));
```

Output:

```
02.04 12:35 [85] (0)
```

P.S. In case of `Android` you should use `Log` class for getting output

Answer (score 0):

During my time here at Oodles Technologies, I learnt a thing or two regarding parsing. I may be able to add here.

Here are the steps:-

**Step-1**. Download jsop jar file from http://jsoup.org/download and add it in your grails/java project.

**Step-2.** use following code to parse html

```
String url = 'www.surveymyapp.com' // html file url
def htmlPage = Jsoup.connect(url).get() // parse html from url
```

**Step-3.** Now we can call different method of jsoup to get data.

for example - 
*To get data by div name 'divName'*

```
def divData = htmlPage.select("div.divName").first().toString().text()
```

*To get image source 'logo'*

```
def imageSrc = detailsInfo.select("img.logo").attr("src")
```